# angular select change event - Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm (change)='selectPartner($event.target.value)' [formControl]='toControl(itemForm.get("invoice").get("idPartner"))'>
   <option [value]="partner.partnerId" *ngFor="let partner of partners"[selected]='currentPartner&&currentPartner.partnerId==partner.partnerId'>
      {{partner.shortName}}
   </option>
</select>
```

I get the error message **`Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`** what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if the error is from typescript and not at runtime, check out this article to see how you can cast the event target to a more specific type: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding-concepts (at the bottom)

Comment: Thank you. you can put this as answer so I can accept it